# How to use the fnSetFilteringDelay method in the new DataTable API?

Tags: jquery, datatable

Guys im using the latest DataTable from [here](https://datatables.net/). Here's my code before which work before that new DataTable API.

```
var table = $('#table-id').dataTable({
  // blah blah blah
}).fnSetFilteringDelay();
```

Now when i used the latest DataTable like this:

```
var table = $('#table-id').DataTable({ //Note the capital letter "D"
  // blah blah blah
}).fnSetFilteringDelay();
```

I get this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` which points to that `fnSetFilteringDelay()` ? So how to properly use this method in the new DataTable API?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have included the plugin either by including the cdn or just inserting it inside a script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        "use strict";

        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnSetFilteringDelay = function (oSettings, iDelay) {
            var _that = this;

            if (iDelay === undefined) {
                iDelay = 250;
            }

            this.each(function (i) {
                $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
                var
                    $this = this,
                    oTimerId = null,
                    sPreviousSearch = null,
                    anControl = $('input', _that.fnSettings().aanFeatures.f);

                anControl.off('keyup search input').on('keyup search input', function () {
                    var $$this = $this;

                    if ( (anControl.val().length == 0 || anControl.val().length >= 3) && (sPreviousSearch === null || sPreviousSearch != anControl.val()) ){
                        window.clearTimeout(oTimerId);
                        sPreviousSearch = anControl.val();
                        oTimerId = window.setTimeout(function () {
                            $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
                            _that.fnFilter(anControl.val());
                        }, iDelay);
                    }
                });

                return this;
            });
            return this;
        };
    });
</script>
```

Once this is done. you define your table and enable your delay

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var TableSelector = $('.grid-mvc table.table');

    var table = TableSelector.DataTable({
        // .... options
    });

    TableSelector.dataTable().fnSetFilteringDelay(600); // delay
</script>
```

Like you already noticed, we have to note the difference between DataTable and dataTable, they are different. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you not include the plugin in the file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fnSetFilteringDelay.js"></script>
```

or cdn

//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/api/fnSetFilteringDelay.js